# Spelling mistakes in published conference paper at IEEE Xplore

Tags: publications

I have published a paper in a conference proceedings of an IEEE conference. The paper has been published since December of last year. Unfortunately, I found some spelling mistakes in the text. Is there a way, how I can correct them? Does anyone have experience with IEEE. On the web I only found information about how to correct metadata (https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/policy-correcting-metadata-in-the-ieee-xplore-digital-library/) but I could not find any information about spelling errors.

Comment: Likely anybody who has published more than one paper has a spelling mistake somewhere out there. Few will notice, almost nobody will care. Relax and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way...I can correct them?

No, published works cannot (generally) be changed. (You can fix typos in copies distributed elsewhere, e.g., e-prints on arxiv.)

Comment: Is that a general answer or one specific to IEEE conferences?

Comment: @Buffy Generally, but exceptions no doubt exist.

Answer (score 2):

It may be impossible to get a change made, but a possible approach would be to contact the program chair of the conference (or the conference chair if necessary) and ask for advice. They will know what is possible and what is not.

But it is also likely that the errors are merely a nuisance and not fatal to the work. It hasn't been a long time, yet, but over a longer period things get harder to change and more likely to be ignored.

Print versions are quite unlikely to be changed for anything but books that go through multiple printings with some editor intervention between printings.